# Javascript currying pattern: getting error while calling function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement currying pattern for sum multiplication in my simple program. For that, I have defined one generic curry function and calling sum and multiply functions in it but I am not getting any output. can anyone tell me what's wrong in my program? Thanks in advance.

code ::

```
function curry(fn) {
    sum.call(this, a,b);
    multiply.call(this, a,b,c);
}

function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function multiply(a, b, c) {
    return a * b * c;
}

const curriedSum = curry(sum);
const curriedMult = curry(multiply);

const addOne = curriedSum(1);
const addTwo = curriedSum(2);
```

Expected Output ::

```
// 1 + 3 = 4
console.log('result', addOne(3));      // 'result'   4


// 1 + 1 = 2
console.log('result', addOne(1));     // 'result'   2


// 2 + 5 = 7
console.log('result', addTwo(5));     // 'result'   7


// 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
console.log('result', curriedMult(2)(3)(4));    // 'result'   24
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I am not getting any output

Comment: Your `curry` function does not curry anything. It also tries to call `sum` with two undefined values, since `a` and `b` are only defined in the actual `sum` function, not the `call`.

Comment: `curry` doesn't have a `return` statement so it returns `undefined` by default (but as  Heretic Monkey said, it actually doesn't finish execution because `a` and `b` are not declared).

Comment: Please see [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314/215552) for examples of curried functions.

Comment: I want to define currying for sum and multiplication that's why I added call in curry function

Comment: I am trying to implement generic method which does both sum and multiplication.

Comment: @Riya the answer you picked isn't currying anything it's just making a function that calls the function passed in. In that answer `addOne` isn't a function it's just a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your curry function the problem is you dont invoke the fn that you are passing, 
you must keep the fn in closure, and return new function which waits to second paremater to invoke itself.

You might want to check [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/i-never-understood-javascript-closures-9663703368e8) great article about clousers;

Also here is the working example of your code;

```js
const curry = (fn) => (...args) => fn(...args)

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function multiply(a, b, c) {
  return a * b * c;
}

const curriedSum = curry(sum);
const curriedMult = curry(multiply);

const addOne = curriedSum(1,2); 
const addTwo = curriedSum(2,3); 
const multiple = curriedMult(2,3,4) 

console.log(addOne)
console.log(addTwo)
console.log(multiple)
```

Comment: This isn't actually [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) anything. It's just wrapping the function in a a new function. The value you are saving in `addOne` is just the result of `1+2` not a new function that adds one to the argument.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a step back and ask what you want that `curry` function to return. The way you are using it suggests you want it to return a function, so it needs to at *least* do that. That function looks like it should also take arguments, because you are using it that way.

So…just return a function that takes arguments and binds them to the function you passed into `curry` and return that.

```
const curry = (fn) => (...a) => fn.bind(null, ...a)
```

This says `curry` is a function that takes a function parameter (`fn`) and returns a new function that takes arguments and returns yet another function that is the result of `fn.bind`

To use it you can:

```js
const curry = (fn) => (...a) => fn.bind(null, ...a)

function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function multiply(a, b, c) {
    return a * b * c;
}

const curriedSum = curry(sum);
const curriedMult = curry(multiply);

const addTwo = curriedSum(2);
console.log(addTwo(10))              // 2 + 10

const mult10 = curriedMult(10)
// because we spread the args in curry you 
// can pass two arguments
console.log(mult10(10, 2))           // 10 * 10 * 2

// or you can even curry it again:
const mult20 = curriedMult(20)
const curriedMult20 = curry(mult20)
const mult20_10 = curriedMult20(10)
console.log(mult20_10(2))            // 20 * 10 * 2
```